# How to unchecked RadioButton on ASP.NET/VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have two radio buttons in ASP.Net as follows:

```
<dx:ASPxRadioButton ID="RB_Type" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Theme="Office365" Text="Type of media" Font-Size="Medium"></dx:ASPxRadioButton>

<dx:ASPxRadioButton ID="RB_Date" runat="server" Theme="Office365" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Date" Font-Size="Medium" ClientInstanceName="RB_Date"></dx:ASPxRadioButton>
```

For example I want that when I select #RB_Type the #RB_Date radiobutton is unchecked and then if I click on #RB_Date the #RB_Type button is unchecked.

To do this I have the following code in VB.NET:

```
If RB_Type.Checked Then

    RB_Date.Checked = False

ElseIf RB_Date.Checked Then

    RB_Type.Checked=False

EndIf
```

But at runtime if I select RB_Type and then click on RB_Date then RB_Type will remain selected and RB_Date will be unchecked.

I would like to find a solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any code at all. You should be setting the `GroupName` property of your `RadioButtons` to the same value for those controls that you want to work as a group. That group will then be inherently mutually-exclusive, i.e. checking one in the group will automatically uncheck any others.

Comment: @Nico2619, what do you not understand about the examples you found on the web when you made the effort to look? That said, why would you need an example of how to set a property of a control when you just posted code that already sets numerous properties of those same controls? I know that you're a beginner but you allowed to try to think for yourself before asking for others to do for you and you're expected to do so.

Comment: For the record, I don't use Web Forms so I consulted the relevant documentation to find this solution. You should have already consulted that documentation yourself before posting here, so you should have already known the answer. ALWAYS read the relevant documentation. It won't always solve your problems but it often will so look first and ask questions later.

Comment: I'm really sorry I got stuck and didn't think to look at the documentation. I managed to apply the `GroupName` and it works. Thanks for your help! I will look more next time :)

Comment: @Nico2619, we all make mistakes and all we can ask is that you learn from them. :-)

Comment: you can use groupname - but I also tend to prefer to use a radio button list - that way, one control, and one event returns the index of the selected radio button (or value). And the radio button list can be directly data bound (driven from a table). So even better is to use the radio button list - it only ever allows one choice, but if you have 6 choices, you get a index (or value) of the choice in one event, and with one line of code. So, my votes and suggestions are to adopt the radio  button list for these types of problems.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal, sounds like a reasonable plan. I don't use Web Forms so just looked up the `RadioButton` control that the user was already using. While my answer does address the OP's question directly, based on what you've said, it sounds like your suggestion is a better solution to the actual problem.